# printing tree results , segmentation error , insertion into tree

Tags: c

Here's the code , i run it with one example it works , but when it comes

to comparing i do not understand what's wrong ? , thanks in advance for

any help .I need to print dictionary texts properly (inserting , printing) ,  can not still come up with a solution , i mean using dictionary data structure like .

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node_s {
  char *element;
  struct Node_s *left, *right;
} Node;

typedef struct {
 Node *head;
} Table;
//Table *initialize();
//Node *createNode(const char *element);

Table *initialize() {
  Table *tb = malloc(sizeof(Table)*1000);
  tb->head = NULL;
  return tb;
}
Node *createNode( char * element ) {
  Node *temp  = malloc(sizeof(temp));
  temp->element  = element ;
  temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
  return temp;
}

 void insert(Table *temp,  char *element) {
 Node *nd = createNode(element);
 Table * place = NULL;
 Node *new = NULL;
 int cmp = 0; 
 if(temp->head == NULL) {
    temp->head= nd;
    printf("empty ! \n");
    return;
 }
 else {
    Table *current = temp;
    while (current!=NULL) {
        cmp = strcmp(current->head->element,element);
        if(cmp < 0)  { 
            current->head= current->head->left;
        }
        else if(cmp > 0)  { 
            current->head = current->head->right;
        }

  } //while
  place = current;
  new = nd;
  if(cmp > 0 ) {
    place->head->right = new ;
  }
  else if(cmp <0 ) { 
    place->head->left = new;
  }
 }
 }   
 void print_table(Table *temp) {
   if(temp!=NULL || !temp->head) return;
    print_table(temp->head->left);
    printf("%s   \n",temp->head->element);
    print_table(temp->head->right);      
 }
 int main () {
  Node * nd = NULL;
  //nd->element = "key";
  // nd = createNode("key");
  Table *tb  = initialize();
  //tb->head = createNode("key");
  //tb->head = createNode("key");
  insert(tb, "table element1");
  insert(tb, "table element2");
  insert(tb, "table element2");
  //nd = createNode("key1");
  // print_table(t);
  //printf("%s \n",nd->element);
  print_table(tb);
  // printf("%s \n",tb->head->element); 
  free(nd);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Do you have all the warnings turned on when you built your program?  There are at least 3 of them, one being that you forgot to `#include <stdio.h>`, and the other is that your call to `print_table()` within the `print_table` function uses the wrong type

Comment: yes , i edited them , but the print_table what should i do , if my parameter is Table , it should be Table , casting doesn't work .

Comment: Your issue starts before you even do the printing.  See my answer.

Comment: this line: 'Table *tb = malloc(sizeof(Table)*1000);' is allocating room for struct Table, which contains nothing but a pointer to struct Node.   This is the first error of many.

Comment: 'new' is a C++ keyword.  If this is compiled with a C++ compiler, the compile will fail.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of potential bugs here, but your primary issue is in the following line of createNode:

```
Node *temp  = malloc(sizeof(temp));
```

Here you're doing a sizeof(temp) and temp is a pointer. This means that you are only allocating enough memory for a pointer (usually 8 bytes). You are hence writing outside of allocating memory when using the left/right members of the heap allocated structure. The fix:

```
Node *temp  = malloc(sizeof(Node));

// EXTRA: I also recommend that you verify that the allocation was successful
if (temp) {
    temp->element  = element ;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
}

return temp;
```

In printTable, you should also verify that temp itself isn't NULL as you are passing the function parameters that might be NULL:

```
if(!temp || !temp->head) return;
```

Also, remove the `free(nd);` at the end of main, as calling free() on  unallocated heap memory corrupts the heap and typically leads to a segfault.

Comment: In insert(), head may be NULL in this line: `cmp = strcmp(current->head->element,element);`

I think you want this instead:

    `cmp = strcmp(current->element,element);`

Comment: You also do the same thing after your compares, replace the instances of `current->head->left;` and `current->head->right;` with only `current->...;` 

And you don't want to set current->head, you only want to set current.

Comment: @RaminTaghizada `as i said i need to use table structs`  If you had turned on your warnings (and not ignored them), you wouldn't be in this situation.  Instead you would (or should have) thought about this very carefully before even attempting to run the program.  Next time, heed the warnings that your compiler is giving you.

Comment: The Table struct is in your example completely unnecessary, you are able to build this binary tree with the Node struct only.

Fixing your code through comments can take forever, so I suggest you go back to scratch and learn from this tutorial first: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson18.html

Answer (score 1):

Your printing method crashes when reaching the last node on the left because it will call print_table(NULL) since there's nothing more on the left. After that when it executes the line

```
if(!temp->head) return;
```

You get a memory access violation because temp is NULL, you should also check if temp itself is NULL.

```
if( !temp || !temp->head ) return;
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One issue right away is on your second call to `insert`:

```
while (current != NULL) {
    cmp = strcmp(current->head->element, element);  // this line
```

You didn't check if `current->head` is NULL itself.  According to what you've implemented, you use `head` as a sentinel, thus it can be NULL.  However, your search loop totally forgot about this condition and assumes that `head` is never NULL.

Your loop doesn't seem fundamentally correct.  You traverse the left, so what is supposed to happen if the left branch "runs out" (as it does now when you call `insert` the second time)?

In addition, your `insert` function has a memory leak.  You potentially allocate 2 new nodes here:

```
Node *nd = createNode(element);
```

and here:

```
new = createNode(element);
```

Only one is stored while the other is leaked.

Another issue is that your tree does nothing in the `while` loop if the two items are equal.  Two equal items results in an infinite loop:

```
while (current!=NULL) 
{
     cmp = strcmp(current->head->element,element);
     if(cmp < 0)  
         current->head= current->head->left;
     else if(cmp > 0)   
         current->head = current->head->right;
     else 
         printf("these are equal   ! \n");  // but we don't do anything with current!
 }
```

If the goal is to not have duplicates, then you should exit this function if a duplicate is found.  If the goal is to store duplicates, only test for `< 0`, anything else, goes on the right branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
This might be what you are looking for.
It handles a doubly linked list

error checking is added
removed undesirable/unnecessary typedef's from struct definitions

corrected the logic to link in new nodes

avoided recursion in the printing of the linked list

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct Node 
{
  char *element;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right;
}; 


// define the head pointer for the linked list
struct Node *head = NULL;




// struct Node *createNode(const char *element);




struct Node *createNode( char * element ) 
{
    struct Node *pNewNode  = NULL;

    if( NULL == (pNewNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)) ) )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for new node failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    pNewNode->element  = element ; // copies a char pointer
    pNewNode->left  = NULL;
    pNewNode->right = NULL;
    return pNewNode;
} // end function: createNode


void insert(char *element) 
{
    int cmp = 0; 
    // get ptr to first node in list
    struct Node *pCurrentNode = head;

    // create the node to be inserted into linked list
    struct Node *pNewNode = createNode(element);


    if (pCurrentNode == NULL) 
    { // then list empty
        head = pNewNode;
        printf("added first node\n");
        return;
    }

    // implied else, not first node

    while (pCurrentNode->right) 
    {
        cmp = strcmp(pCurrentNode->element,element);

        if(cmp < 0)  
        { 
            // insert new node before current node
            pNewNode->right = pCurrentNode;
            pNewNode->left  = pCurrentNode->left;
            pCurrentNode->left = pNewNode;
            (pNewNode->left)->right = pNewNode;
        }

        else if(cmp > 0)  
        { 
            // step to next node
            pCurrentNode = pCurrentNode->right;
        } // end if

        // note: if data same, don't insert new node
    } //while


    if( pCurrentNode->right == NULL )
    { // then, reached end of list
        // append new node to end of list
        pNewNode->left = pCurrentNode;
        pNewNode->right = NULL;
        pCurrentNode->right = pNewNode;
    } // end if
}  // end function: insert


void print_table() 
{
     struct Node *pCurrentNode = head;

     if( pCurrentNode == NULL ) return;

     // implied else, list not empty

     while( pCurrentNode )
     {
         printf("%s   \n",pCurrentNode->element);
         pCurrentNode = pCurrentNode->right;
    } // end while     
} // end function: print_table


void cleanup()
{
    struct Node *pCurrentNode = head;

    while( pCurrentNode )
    {
        pCurrentNode = pCurrentNode->right;
        free( pCurrentNode->left );
    }
} // end function: cleanup


int main () 
{   
    // exercise the insert function
    insert("table element1"); // append first element
    insert("table element2"); // append second element
    insert("table element4"); // append third element
    insert("table element3"); // insert forth element
    insert("table element3"); // duplicate within list
    insert("table element4"); // duplicate at end of list

    print_table();

    cleanup();
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: this compiles/links, however it was not tested

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different implementation, it compiles and works, it does not allow duplicates.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define ELEMENT_SIZE 1024

typedef struct Node_s
{
    char element[ELEMENT_SIZE];
    struct Node_s *left, *right;
} Node;


Node * createNode(char *element)
{
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    memcpy(node->element, element, ELEMENT_SIZE);
    return node;
}

void free_node(Node *node)
{
    if(!node)
        return;
    free_node(node->left);
    free_node(node->right);
    free(node);
}

Node * insert(Node **head_ptr,  char *element)
{
    Node *head = *head_ptr;
    if(head == NULL){
        Node *node = createNode(element);
        head = node;
        *head_ptr = node;
        return node;
    }else{
        int comp = strcmp(head->element, element);
        if(comp < 0){
            // go left
            if(head->left == NULL){
                // set element to be temp left
                Node *node = createNode(element);
                head->left = node;
                return node;
            }else{
                return insert(&head->left, element);
            }

        }else if(comp > 0){
            // go right
            if(head->right == NULL){
                // set element to be temp left
                Node *node = createNode(element);
                head->right = node;
                return node;
            }else{
                return insert(&head->right, element);
            }
        }else{
            // element exists
            printf("Element \"%s\" already exists\n", element);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}

void print_table(Node *temp)
{
    if(!temp)
        return;
    printf("%s   \n",temp->element);
    print_table(temp->left);
    print_table(temp->right);
}

int main ()
{
    Node *nd = NULL;
    printf("Address of nd is %p\n", &nd);

    Node *n1 = insert(&nd, "table element 1");
    n1 = insert(&nd, "table element 2");
    n1 = insert(&nd, "table element 3");

    n1 = insert(&nd, "element 1");
    n1 = insert(&nd, "element 2");
    n1 = insert(&nd, "element 3");

    n1 = insert(&nd, "alternative 1");
    n1 = insert(&nd, "alternative 2");
    n1 = insert(&nd, "alternative 3");

    n1 = insert(&nd, "alternative 1");
    n1 = insert(&nd, "alternative 2");
    n1 = insert(&nd, "alternative 3");

    print_table(nd);

    free_node(nd);
    return 0;
}
```